What to do when 2 light switches are too far apart for the light switch cover plate?
I replaced the old toggle switches (cover plate fit fine) in my bathroom with rocker switches to update the look. The new rocker switches sit slightly too far apart for the cover plate to sit over them. I have them adjusted to be as close together as possible but they are still about 1/8" too far apart for the cover plate.
I could custom build a plate out of thin wood but am wondering if there is a store-bought option that'll save me time?



This is usually done with a single box that holds two switches rather than two separate boxes. That ensures that the spacing is correct.

Yeah, as @PeteBecker says, you should have one two-gang box instead of two single-gang boxes.

Metal boxes can usually be made to become two gang, but by the time you take them out, it will be easy to just replace with a two gang.

Do you have a picture of the old cover plate that fit fine?   It might be helpful to know how that was accomplished.

The only correct fix here is to remove the two separate boxes and replace them with a single "2-gang" box that is meant for two switches.
Two hack fixes:

Cut two regular single switch covers and join them together to make a custom cover with wider spacing.

Get a double switch that only takes up one spot, and leave the other box empty.  You can then buy a store-bought cover that has one decora opening and one blank like the one below, and hope it covers the entire hole in the wall:




The screw holes on the plate you show probably aren't going to line up, either. I'm curious, since the OP has accepted this Answer, if I'm wrong about that?


Turn off the power to this lighting circuit.
Undo the two switches so they dangle.
Use a round rattail file to extend this slot 
Blow out any shavings and metal dust
Reassemble - you might want to put a washer between screwhead and newly-extended slot.

Remember - hiding crimes behind the faceplate is perfectly okay, as long as its still clamped down securely and is safe to operate.

If you're sliding things this much then there is a serious risk of screws on the inner side of each switch touching the box. Highly recommend a preventive wrap of electrical tape.

Or replace the metal boxes with plastic ones – but then you could replace the two one-gang boxes with a two-gang one, as others have suggested. Either is certainly more professional than electrical tape (which would be my least preferred option).

Looks like there is plenty of gap between the two boxes - it would probably be possible to re-attach one of them so they sit closer together.

Really, the easy button here may be to use a bigger spacer on the right box, to close up the spacing between the two boxes.  Without measurements, impossible to say whether that'll be enough.  Looks like a 1/4" piece of plywood is currently being used; perhaps increasing that to 1/2" will be enough.

Visually, I’d say that closing the gap between the two boxes will be enough or even more – in which case you can still move the switches within their respective boxes so they’ll be slightly further apart.

Get a Dremel or a file and widen the mounting holes for each switch by 1/16".

I thought of that too, but it will move the terminals way too close to the wall of the (metal) box.

Just 3D print a custom cover.
If you have a 3D printer.
If not. Find a friend that has one.
If not. Then send the file to a third party 3D printing house for cheap.
If not then I’m out of ideas.
